# Serial data logging using Arduino and pySerial

Tags: android, python, arduino, pyserial

I have a temperature sensor ([LM35](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm35.pdf)) interfaced with an Arduino board and my [sketch](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Sketch) is able to log values to the serial port, say `/dev/ttyACM0` in Ubuntu, and I was able to install pySerial and log the temperature values into a file... I used the command

```
python -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/ttyACM0 >> templogger.csv
```

So it will log values like

```
27
28
27
```

into the templogger.csv file.

My requirement is to log the system time also along with this, that is, like

```
Tue Jun 11 18:42:37 IST 2013,27
Tue Jun 11 18:42:38 IST 2013,28
Tue Jun 11 18:42:39 IST 2013,27
```

and then possibly plot these values stored in the [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file to an Android client. How should I proceed? What would be a script to log time and temperature together?

Answer (score 1):

Save following script as 'with_time.py':

```
import sys
import time
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(sys.argv[1:], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, bufsize=-1)
# for line in sys.stdin: # This cause buffering!
while True:
    line = p.stdout.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    line = time.ctime() + ',' + line
    sys.stdout.write(line)
p.wait()
```

and run following command:

```
python with_time.py python -u -m serial.tools.miniterm /dev/ttyACM0 >> templogger.csv
```

Comment: What about plotting time-temp graph preferably in an android client

Comment: android client? Which app do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try qcsvlog - it plots chart directly from serial port: https://github.com/ncp1402/qcsvlog

Comment: Link is dead, but there's still a fork available here: https://github.com/eswizardry/qcsvlog